# unable to delete input source option on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm encountering a shortcut contradiction problem so I want to change the keyboard shortcut of changing input methods from `ctrl+shift` to another one. However, I was only able to change one of the shortcut as shown in the `next source` column. (in the picture)

[image: the screenshot of the situation]

I could only change the `shift+super+space` and `shift+space` in `Settings->keyboard shortcuts->typing`. I also tried to modify the configuration file (`/etc/default/keyboard`) but nothing worked to modify that `ctrl+shift`. I'm really out of idea now, could anyone help me please? Thank you so much.